# intellij scala plugin won't compile after package rename

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm using intellij  14.0.2 build#ic-139.659 and scala plugin 1.2.1
Im working on a basic project for a while and everything went well until i **rename a package name**.

Since then im getting this error  and i cant compile and run the program

```
Error:(10, 8) not found: object Repo
import Repo._
           ^
```

When i'm generating the same code to **eclipse** it compile and run well.

Is that a bug or i`m doing something wrong ?

thanks,

miki

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: @GáborBakos i regenerate the project via activator ui and clean the cache ...
same result

Comment: Have you tried importing it with the full path? (src.whatever.whavtever2.Repo)?